# HTML - simple input to .txt

Tags: html, input, submit

I am trying to figure out how to make a simple html code so that whenever anyone on the page types anything into the provided text box and hits submit, it adds that written text to an already existing .txt file on my server.

UPDATE 2/20/14 9:29AM: Well that's unfortunate. I kind of figured I required a .php but sadly my wepbage is hosted through homestead and they do not have .php functionality. Was just hoping there was a workaround. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: What server-side code are you using?  The best the HTML code can do is submit a request to the server with the data.  You'll need some kind of functionality on the server to accept that data and write the file.

Comment: I agree with David, you will need to use something like php to write to a text file on the server

Answer (score 0):

If your server can run php then the following page can be requested when the user clicks submit. (using post method)

```
<?php

    $in = $_POST['name'];
    $file = 'names.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // Append a new person to the file
    $current .= $in;
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use PHP to do this. Make the form action on your form link to a PHP script and inside have something like this.

```
<?php
    $file = 'test.txt';
    $currentText = file_get_contents($file);
    $currentText .= $_POST['text'];
    file_put_contents($file, $currentText);
?>
```